# modify AndroidManifest.xml in custom plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-manifest

In gradle, I want to modify   `android:minSdkVersion` in my custom plugin.

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

I would like to complete like following.

```
void apply(Project project) {
    File manifest = project.file("${project.buildDir}/intermediates/manifests/full/${projectFlavorName}/${buildTypeName}/AndroidManifest.xml")
    def manifestXml = new XmlParser().parse(manifest)
    manifestXml.uses-sdk.attribute("android:minSdkVersion") = 20
}
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Show as following:

```
File Manifest = getManifest()
        def manifestXml = new XmlParser().parse(Manifest)
        manifestXml."uses-sdk".replaceNode{
            'uses-sdk'(' android:minSdkVersion="12"\n' +
                    '    android:targetSdkVersion="14"')
        }
        def fw=new FileWriter(Manifest.toString())
        new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(fw)).print(manifestXml)
```